# Dual vector fields of Maurer-Cartan forms.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider, for example, the Lie group $M$ of affine transformations of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$  given by
$$ M = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: x > 0 \right\}.$$
Obviously, as a $2$-differentiable manifold, $M$ is parametrized by $\varphi: \mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}\to M, (x, y) \mapsto \varphi(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $. Now we want to find the left-invariants forms of $M$. For an arbitrary element $X \in M$ the Maurer-Cartan matrix
$$ \Omega = X^{-1}\text{d} X  = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\text{d}x}{x} & \frac{\text{d}y}{x} \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $$
gives us the left-invariant forms $\omega^{1} = \text{d}x / x$ and $\omega^{2} = \text{d}y / x$. Naturally, now we want to know the dual vector fields of these two forms. Considering the left-traslation $L_{A}: M \to M, X \mapsto AX$, say $A = \begin{pmatrix} a  & b \\
0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, we can think as $L_{A}$ as a mapping $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$(x, y) \mapsto (ax, ay + b),$$
as in fact $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}$. So now let's compute the jacobian matrix
$$ \text{d} L_{A}(X) = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & a 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The columns of this matrix are vector fields in $M$. Say
$$X_{1} = x \partial_{x} \quad \& \quad X_{2}= x\partial_{y}.$$
It's not difficult to see that the vector fields obtained by this way will be always left-invariant.
My question is: why are the vector fields obtained this way the dual frame of the forms $\omega^{1}$ and $\omega^{2}$? Is this a general fact? (at least in linear Lie groups, as I have done other similar examples). Thanks in advance.

Comment: By invariance, you only have to check the duality statement at the identity. Can you see it now?

Comment: This is what I've thought: $\text{d}L_{A}: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is an isomorphism of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} \simeq T_{e}M$, so the jacobian matrix at the identity element will always be the identity element. Now, the Maurer-Cartan matrix $\Omega$ is the only map $\Omega: TM \to T_{e}M \simeq \mathfrak{g}$ such that $\Omega_{e}: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$  is the identity map. I think this is enough to show duality. Am I right?

Comment: How does $L_A$ map the identity to the identity? I think you have the right idea, but it seems muddled here.